# Elasticsearch partial query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-7

I am working with the Elasticsearch v 7.3.1 and trying to implement a partial search. All searches are going well, but when I query "**John Oxford**", "John" matches with the document, but there is no "**Oxford**" in the entire doc. But still shows me the document instead of showing the empty results.

How can I do it, so that it does not return the document when we query **John Oxford**?

My mapping, settings, sample doc and query of student data are below.

**Mappings**

```
PUT student
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "DOB" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "email" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "first_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "home_phone" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "last_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "student_id" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Sample Document**

```
POST student/_doc
{
    "DOB": "1983-12-04",
    "email": "johndoe@gmail.fr",
    "first_name": "john",
    "home_phone": 1242432,
    "last_name": "doe",
    "student_id": 28

}
```

**Query**

```
GET student/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "john oxford",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "fields": [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "DOB",
        "home_phone",
        "student_id"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Following are the results that I want**

- 1242 - partially matches home_phone
- joh do - partial match against "John" and "Doe"
- 1983-12-04 - matches the DOB
- johndoe - partial match on email
- doe - match last name

Comment: Sorry, can't understand you... if you want a partial search, the term "john" could be a partial result of "john oxford". Do you want to search if the expression "john oxford" is into your documents? or you would retrieve all doc that have both terms, john and oxford?

Comment: @Lupanoide please check the updated question. I have updated the requirements. My requirements should meet.

Comment: @Lupanoide kindly help me in achieving my goal. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement the partial search you should add the specific `autocomplete analyzer` to the required text fields and implement a specific `search_analyzer` because you are using a `edgengram` filter - please read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) for explanation. This is more comfortable than specify an analyzer during query time, as you have done. Try:

```
PUT student
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "DOB" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "email" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "first_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "home_phone" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "last_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "student_id" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then when you query for autocompletion of two terms, you should concatenate them with the `and` operator. For your use case [cross-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) type should be the best:

```
GET student/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "John Oxford",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields": [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "DOB",
        "home_phone",
        "student_id"
      ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you. Have a nice day :-)